# Simulate Android application flushed out of memory

Tags: android, memory-management, emulation

I have an Android app that logs in to a server, gets a session ID and uses it for as long as the app is running. The session ID is stored in the `SharedPeferences` .

For some reason, on one device (an old Samsung Galaxy S), sometimes when the application wakes up, the session ID is gone - it can't be retrieved from the SharedPreferences, and instead - null is returned. This happens probably after some heavy use of the phone, requiring Android to free up memory resources. Note that the application is still alive, it isn't restarted from scratch - my activity just gets onResume called.

I'd be really happy if I could reproduce this behavior on the emulator. Is there a way to nudge the emulator into doing the same thing?

Comment: Have you tried reducing the resources on the emulator to that of the Samsung Galaxy S or further even?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd be surprised if your activity isn't also getting onCreate in those situations. A strategy for testing this kind of thing on the emulator is to pause all activities in your application and then using adb to kill the process. That's basically what the framework does when it runs short of resources. When you resume the activity, it creates a new process and tries to reinitialize your activity from the state that was saved when it was paused.

Comment: How would you incorporate this into your workflow? I need to simulate having the os kill the app so that I can track down a NulLReference Exception.

Comment: nm... killing the app is not what I need... it's more like a hibernate state that I'm looking for.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - To simulate having the os kill the app, suspend your app (by, say, pressing Home or simulating a phone call). Then use the ADB to kill the app's process. I'm aware of no "hibernate" state in Android; can you elaborate on what you need to do?

Comment: yeah I'm not sure of the term. There's this state that the app goes in when it's not killed, but kind of hibernating. This happens when I go to the home screen and then put my phone in my pocket for a couple of hours. When I re-open the app, it doesn't launch fresh (IE: there's no splash screen), but it also doesn't jump straight to the last activity. It shows a blank activity for a short amount of time while it's re-initializing some bits. It's in this state that I get a NullReferenceException on my IoC container.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell - That sounds very much like the os killed the app's process. The blank activity is probably the os trying to recover the activity at the top of the task stack for your app. Whether the app crashes or not may depend on which activity was at the top of the stack when the app was paused. Pausing the app and killing the app's process through the adb should reliably simulate the same sequence of events.